# How to display two Qt models using external data in a single tree view

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt4

I'm working on a C++/Qt project. I have two business models (one is a hierarchical tree-like structure, i.e. film categories/sub-categories, and the other one is a simple vector, i.e. film titles which can belong only to a subcategory) and I want to display both in a unique tree-view, where leaf nodes can belong to both models and non-leaf nodes belong to the first model. In addition to this view, I also want to display in model specific views, a tree-view for the first model and a list view for the second one.

I've considered 3 approaches:

1) Create one QAbstractItemModel for each business model and another one to represent the mixed model. Thus, each view is associated with only one model.

2) Create only two QAbstractItemModel for each business model and implement a special view that deals with that information.

3) Use a QStandardItem model and implement subclasses of QStandardItem for both my business model elements.

Because I'm working with external data, I don't want to duplicate any information if possible.

What do you think is the best/proper approach to follow? Any implementation advices?

Answer (score 0):

QDataWidgetMapper is your best bet in that one.

Answer (score 0):

Make one model of your data.  I would make one tree model, which is option c of your choices, but could be implementing your own tree model.

For the list view, see if you can't set the tree model on it as well, and use [setRootIndex](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setRootIndex) to only show the list of items you want to see.  I know it works on table and tree views, so I assume it would also work on a list view.